# NodeJs - Paginated table with filters - Problem with query generation

Tags: node.js, filter, pagination

I have a paginated table with filters, here's my `nodejs` method to return the paginated data

```
async findPaginated(
    pagesToSkip: number,
    pagesToTake: number,
    filters?: IPaginatedDataFilters,
  ): Promise<IPaginatedResult<ICommonFields>> {

  const queryBuilder = this.radarRepository.createQueryBuilder('radar');

  queryBuilder
    .select('radar.nombre', 'nombre')
    .addSelect('radar.id', 'id')
    .addSelect('radar.ubicacion', 'ubicacion')
    .addSelect('provincia.nombre', 'provincia')
    .leftJoin('radar.provincia', 'provincia')
    .leftJoin('radar.municipio', 'municipio')
    .addSelect('municipio.nombre', 'municipio')
    .addSelect('radar.status', 'status')
    .addSelect("'Radar'", 'tipo');

  if (filters?.searchedColumns?.length) {
    const searchParameter = filters.searchParameter;
    const searchedColumns = filters.searchedColumns;

    if (searchedColumns[0] === "ubicacion") {
      queryBuilder.andWhere("radar.ubicacion LIKE :ubicacion", { ubicacion: `%${searchParameter}%` });
    } else if (searchedColumns[0] === "municipio") {
      const municipio = await this.municipioRepository.findOne({ where: { nombre: Like(`%${searchParameter}%`) } });

      if (municipio) {
        queryBuilder.andWhere("radar.municipioId = :municipioId", { municipioId: municipio.id });
      } else {
        const data = [];
        const totalCount = 0;
        return { data, totalCount };
      }
    } else if (searchedColumns[0] === "nombre") {
      queryBuilder.andWhere("radar.nombre LIKE :nombre", { nombre: `%${searchParameter}%` });
    } else if (searchedColumns[0] === "status") {
      queryBuilder.andWhere("radar.status = :status", { status: searchParameter });
    }
  } 

  queryBuilder.orderBy('radar.nombre', 'ASC');
  queryBuilder.offset(pagesToSkip).limit(pagesToTake);
  console.log(queryBuilder.getQuery());

  const data = await queryBuilder.getRawMany();
  const totalCount = await queryBuilder.getCount();

  return {
    data,
    totalCount,
  };
  }
```

the problem here is that if i'm in for example page three and apply filters, it will ignore the records in previous pages, when it should return all the records that matches that filter condition

I've tried putting the offset in(0) when filters are applied but that broke the page navigation because brings back always the same records.